# Show total pages in react-data-table-component DataTable pagination

Tags: reactjs, datatable, pagination

I am new to react and just started using DataTable from react-data-table-component. In the provided pagination support it only shows the number of records out of total number of records found.
eg :- 1-10 of 35 (When there is only 35 records in total)

I want to show which page no the user currently at instead of number of records.
FOr eg - if I use 10 records per page above example should show "1 of 4" (Since we have only total of 4 pages)

Is there a way to do this with react-data-table-component?

If not what are the recommended DataTable components that supports this?

Comment: If you take a look at the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-table-component#pagination), there is enough information on how to achieve what you want to do with your pagination. You could also check out this [demo](https://jbetancur.github.io/react-data-table-component/?path=/story/basic--pagination) that shows what you want to achieve.

Comment: All those are having no of rows as the total count. Which option are you referring specifically to do what I want?

Comment: You can try changing the object prop named `paginationComponentOptions`, which overrides the options for the built in pagination component.